# Loop through a file with stored file paths and remove those files

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a problem with bash script that should go through every line in **ready.txt** file which has stored paths to files and then do something with them like in this case **rm -f**

ready.txt contents:

```
'/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI2.pdf'
'/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI4.pdf'
'/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI6.pdf'
```

My loop that **should delete** thoese files but **doesn't do that.**

```
while read -r line;
do
    rm -f $line
done < ready.txt
```

I tested it manually:

`export line='/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI2.pdf'`

`rm -f $line`

or:

`rm -f '/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI2.pdf'`

Both of these I tested works as intended, but loop doesn't want to.

I a newbie in bash scripts. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does `ready.txt` contain quotes `'` themselves?

Comment: Yes it does contain ```'```

Comment: @spyx33 That's why it doesn't work. You need to remove from passing to rm (or you could from the `read.txt` itself, too). In any case, use double quotes for the variable `line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the filenames contain single quotes in your input file `ready.txt` (unless the actual filenames do contain quotes, which I doubt) as `rm` doesn't find such files.

You need to remove them:

```
while read -r line;
do
    rm -f "${line//\'}"
done < ready.txt
```

Also, see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/1275169)

Comment: Yup this is a correct answer now it does work with ```'``` quotes! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something?

Checking your scripts with http://shellcheck.net before posting here.

Assuming the input file contiains:

```
/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI2.pdf
/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI4.pdf
/home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI6.pdf
```

Quote every variable expansion to prevent word splitting:

```
rm -f "$line"
```

Most probably `rm -f $line` "works" in your shell because you are using zsh, not bash, while in script you use bash or sh.

Also `read -r line` will remove leading and trailing spaces. Use:

```
while IFS= read -r line
```

For more information, research word splitting, when and how to use quoting in shell, how double quotes differ from single quotes. Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 .

To execute a command for each line of a file, use `xargs`, typically:

```
xargs -d '\n' rm < ready.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the http://shellcheck.net tool! I newer heard of it and I already know I will be using it a lot :D

Comment: I really complicated it :D I have 2 files one with ```'``` quotes and one without them. Solution you posted works for the one without ```'``` quotes so it's a lot simpler than my previous. I couldn't get it to work before because spaces were messing it up but now it works great with ```while IFS= read -r line```